# How to populate nested data in MongoDB using mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-populate

I have three schemas(**BlogSchema, UserSchema, commentSchema**) in MongoDB. How can I populate the nested data.

#### BlogSchema:

```
const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true, minLength: 5 },
  author: String,
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  comments: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Comment",
    },
  ],
});
```

#### UserSchema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, minLength: 4 },
  name: String,
  passwordHash: String,
  blogs: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Blog",
    },
  ],
});
```

#### CommentSchema

```
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  comment: { type: String, minLength: 5 },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  blog: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Blog",
    required: true,
  },
});
```

I want my data, blog in the **following format**:

```json
blog = {
"title" : ".....",
"author": "......",
"user" : user-Id,
comments: [{comment:"....",
user: "username"}]
```

**One of the solution I tried is**

```js
 const blogs = await Blog.find({})
    .populate("user", { id: 1 })
    .populate("comments", { comment: 1, user: 1 });
```

But, the output it provides is as follows(*not on required format*):

```json
blog = {
"title" : ".....",
"author": "......",
"user" : user-Id,
comments: [{comment:"....",
user: "user-Id"}]
```

**How can I get the required result by populate or by any other method?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use nested populate to be able to populate the `user` objects within the `comments` objects if using `Model.find()` on the `Blog`. Here is an example:

```js
const blogs = await Blog.find()
.populate({ path: 'user', model: userModel })
.populate({
    path: 'comments',
    model: commentModel,
    populate: {
        path: 'user', model: userModel, select: 'username -_id',
    },
});
```

I have included `model: modelName` in each populate incase as you may need to register the model. This depends on your design of course and can be removed.

You will notice I have used `select: 'username -_id'` inside the nested `populate` object. This means select `username` and exclude `_id`. You can add properties and exclude them as you see fit. If you do not want this then you can remove it and your `user` object will contain everything from the `userSchema`.

Answer (score 0):

try with
const blogs = await Blog.find({})
.populate("category", { username: 1, _id: 1 });